# On click of App link automatic downloading is not happening for the Instant app Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, instant

I have developed an Instant app and uploaded to the Internal test track on play store. Everything is working fine but when I hit the App link registered with Instant app, automatic downloading is not happening.

Comment: Are you sure the registration link is for downloading ? I think it is just to be registered as a tester. Then you need to download the application in google store.

Comment: When user click on links to an app (from search, emails or ads, and more), Apps may open with Google Play Instant and let you try them before installing.